# How to connect to Visual Studio Online from Visual Studio 2012 Express

Tags: visual-studio-2012, azure-devops

As title says.

I opened the team explorer view, clicked on connect, then on server -> add,
and put in the url I got online while creating my Visual Studio Online project (http://_my_team_name_.visualstudio.com), for which I selected to use TFS.

It then says that could not connect to the TFS due to a certain list of reasons like port configuration error (I left the one suggested - 8080) or wrong combination user/password (which I had not specified anywhere - dunno if it has to be specified somewhere).

In general I could not find any guided instruction to perform the connection, because everything I found requires Visual Studio 2013, which I have not.
I do know that I could use it easily by downloading it but, just for information, would be nice to know how to do this with VS 2012.

Any hint would be appreciated

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to connect with SSL, on the default port (443).  For example:

```
https://_my_team_name_.visualstudio.com/
```

Comment: Great! should have guessed it for the https specification!

Comment: Also important part related for credential https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/6fb8272b-df51-42c2-ad3d-97a730a284cb/tf31003-when-trying-to-connect-to-team-foundation-service-from-vs-2012?forum=TFService